# Alert users if user do not have enough points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to create a function where points could not be deducted if users have not enough points. I'm using MVC to do it.
It will prompt user that they have not enough points to get an answer from the questions. 
     Answer

Comment: Have your action method execute the relevant code and generate the response(which has a message) and you can use the response in the success event handler to show that message to user.

Comment: @Shyju can u show me how to do it? thank you

Comment: What specifically you want to know. your current question is too broad. Specify what specific things you have trouble getting to work.

Comment: alert user when they have not enough points to buy an answer

Comment: I would like to write an answer to help you. But how do I know when user does not have enough points ?

Answer (score 0):

You may make Ajax Get function from Jquery .. to get the points of the person

then you can check if the points of the person greater than 10 .. do something
else show alert ..

Example:

```
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want an answer? It will deduct 10 points.")) {                
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "@Url.Content("~/")API/PointsTransaction/PointsTransactAnswer",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",               
        success: function(obj) {

        // let make * Ppoints * is person points that we have gitten from Ajax
    if (Ppoints > 10 ) {
     // show the answer
    }else {
    alert("oops, you don't have enough points to show this answer")
    }

        }
    });   
    }
```

and also .. you can use Jquery to make function when use click the button .

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#answer').click(function() {
  // what to do if the button clicked
  })
  })
```

hope i've help you!
and sorry for my bad english .

Answer (score 0):

hi @rod in your ajax call u can get the points of user and at the time of success if points is greater than 10 u can do rest of things

```
< a href = "#" class = "btn"  id = "answer" onclick = "return Confirm()" > Answer < /a> 



    < script type = "text/javascript" >
                 "use strict";
                 function Confirm() {

                 var text;
                         if (confirm("Are you sure you want an answer? It will deduct 10 points.")) {
                 $.ajax({
                 type: "post",
                         url: "@Url.Content("~/")API/PointsTransaction / PointsTransactAnswer",
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         success: function(obj) {
                         if (obj.points > 10){
                             // do whatever you want if points of user is grater than 10 .
                         } else{
                             // if points of user is less than 10 show message.
                             alert('Oops. points is less than 10 . ');
                         }

                         }
                 });
                         text = "";
                         return true;
                 } else {
                 return false;
                 }


                 }
```